# Cannot paste text in CodeMirror in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, clipboard, codemirror

There was no problem some months ago but suddenly "Paste" stop working in CodeMirror in Google Chrome. Both "Ctrl+V", "Shift+Insert" and right-click -> "Paste" do nothing.

It's not a bug in my code because even at demo page at
http://codemirror.net/jstest.html
it doesn't work.

Comment: It works in my Chrome (version 6.0.472.63)

Comment: I've got Google Chrome 8.0.552.0 dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Google Chrome.
Everything works in the new version - Google Chrome 8.0.552.0 dev

Answer (score 3):

This problem continues on Linux when using any webkit variant (Chrome is one).  It remains unhandled in CodeMirror 2.25.

Here is the [bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85642).

You can make a VERY PARTIAL patch to `handleKeyBinding(e)` in CodeMirror after `var name=...`  This is NOT a perfect fix, but it will help you recognize <kbd>Delete</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>:

```
if( name == null && (webkit || chrome) && e.keyCode == 0 && e.charCode == 0 && e.keyLocation == 3 ) {
    // Now we know something on the keypad has been pressed and not translated properly by webkit.
    if( e.ctrlKey == false && e.shiftKey == false ) {
      // We're probably hitting the Delete key to delete a character.
      name = 'Delete';    
    }
    if( e.ctrlKey == true || e.shiftKey == true ) {
      // We're probably using Ctrl-Ins to copy, or Shift-Ins to paste.
      name = 'Insert';    
    }
  }
```

Now <kbd>Delete</kbd> is handled.  But since you can't get to the clipboard from Javascript, you are stuck with respect to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> (copy) and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>(paste) until the webkit bug is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem - however, I found this instance of it does accept copy-paste from within chrome.

http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/interactive/index.html

I've tried to use their copy of the chromemirror source code on my site - but no luck yet